# Thresholding in intermediate layer using Gumbel Softmax

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, softmax, activation-function

In a neural network, for an intermediate layer, I need to threshold the output. The output of each neuron in the layer is a real value, but I need to binarize it (to 0 or 1). But with hard thresholding, backpropagation won't work. Is there a way to achieve this?

**Details:**
I have a GAN kind of network i.e. there are 2 neural networks trained end-to-end. The output of first neural network is real values. I need them to be binary values. I read that Gumbel Softmax (Categorical Reparameterization) is used to handle discrete variables in a neural network. Is there a way to use that for my use-case? If yes, how? If not, is there any other way?

From what I could gather in internet is that Gumbel is a probability distribution. Using that we can generate a discrete distribution. But for use-case, I need a function that can take a real input and output a binary value. So, I need an activation function of that form. How can I achieve that?
Thanks!